# Sum of two squares - Number of steps in Fermat descent

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares

If a prime $p$ can be written as the sum of two squares, then one can construct this representation via Fermat descent if we know an $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv −1 \mod p$. Is there a possibility to say how much steps the Fermat descent will have without just going through the descent?

I have also posted this question on MathStackExchange a week ago ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116838/sum-of-two-squares-number-of-steps-in-fermat-descent)), but received no answer. I hope it is ok to post it here, too.

EDIT: For example, let $p=1553$. Then $x=339$ and $339^2 + 1^2 = 74 \cdot 1553$. With the descent, we next compute numbers $x_2$, $y_2$ with $x_2^2+y_2^2 = k \cdot 1553$ with $k < 74$. In this case, $x_2=-142$, $y_2=5$ and $x_2^2+y_2^2=13 \cdot 1553$. Going on, in the next step we get $(-9)^2 + (-55)^2 = 2 \cdot 1553$ and finally $(-32)^2 + 23^2 = 1 \cdot 1553$. So here we have three steps: $74 \mapsto 13, 13 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 1$.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I.e., define what exactly you mean by a "Fermat descent step", if you want exact numbers or bounds, ... Note that the number of steps will usually depend on the square root of $-1$ mod $p$ you start with.

Comment: @Michael: I made an edit, I hope it is clear now what I mean with "step"

Comment: How did you compute $x_2$?

Comment: From the example, it appears that the following is used: assume you have $x,y$ with $x^2 + y^2 = kp$. Then take $x' + iy' = (x + iy)(u - iv)/k$ where $u,v$ are the absolutely smallest remainders of $x,y$ mod $k$. In the example, $u = -31$, $v = 1$, which leads to $(x_2, y_2) = (-142, -5)$.

Comment: Yes, that is the way I computed $x_2,y_2$.

Answer (score 3):

In each iteration of Fermat descent, the multiple of $p$ written as a sum of two squares is at least divided by 2. So if you start with $x>0$ satisfying $x\equiv -1\mod p$, the procedure ends in at most $\log_2(\frac{x^2+1}{p})$ iterations.

Comment: Why x/p? x<p, so the log_2() is negative.

Comment: Dear joro: Thanks for spotting that. It's now fixed.

Comment: In the example above this bound would be $6$, whereas the exact number of steps is $3$, so this is a bit too rough. Also, I am more interested in a lower bound.

Comment: @Martin A well-known an plausible conjecture of Landau (and many others) says that $x^2 + 1$ is a prime number for infinitely many integers $x$. This implies that the lower bound is $0$ steps, since $p = x^2 + 1$ is already a sum of two squares and $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $l$ be the square root of $-1$: $l^2+1\equiv 0 \mod p$. Then from factorization $x^2+y^2\equiv(x+ly)(x-ly)$ we see that a set
$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:x^2+y^2\equiv 0\mod p\}$$ is the union of two latticies
$$\Lambda_\pm=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:x\pm ly\equiv 0\mod p\}.$$
Each step of Fermat descent is almost the same (but not exactly the same) as a step from Gauss reduction of given basis $(0,p)$, $(\mp l,1)$. It means that it works like "nearest integer continued fraction" algorithm. But vectors $(x_k,y_k)$ may jump between $\Lambda_+$ and $\Lambda_-$, numbers $x_k$, $y_k$ may be reminders or swapped reminders and so on. If you'll need more details on Fermat descent then it will be necessary to take care about all these technical difficulties.